# How to render a Float32Array cube with vtk.js?

Tags: javascript, volume-rendering, vtk.js

I want to render a 3D volume with vtk.js. My issue is that all the tutorials/examples in the vtk.js documentation load and render `vti` files. In my case, my data is just a `Float32Array` which contains the values of a 3D image. How can I volume-render that using vtk.js? I need a solution that creates no additional files on the file system.

Comment: Did you ever find out how to do it? I'm currently trying to do the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed (with a coworker's help) to render a random cube volume like this:

```js
// pseudo imports (avoids having to use fully qualified names)
var vtkFullScreenRenderWindow = vtk.Rendering.Misc.vtkFullScreenRenderWindow;
var vtkImageData = vtk.Common.DataModel.vtkImageData;
var vtkDataArray = vtk.Common.Core.vtkDataArray;
var vtkVolume = vtk.Rendering.Core.vtkVolume;
var vtkVolumeMapper = vtk.Rendering.Core.vtkVolumeMapper;
var vtkColorTransferFunction = vtk.Rendering.Core.vtkColorTransferFunction;
var vtkPiecewiseFunction = vtk.Common.DataModel.vtkPiecewiseFunction;

var VtkDataTypes = vtkDataArray.VtkDataTypes;

function initRandomCubeVolume() {
    var width = 50, height = 50, depth = 50;
    var size = width * height * depth;

    var values = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        values[i] = Math.random();
    }

    var scalars = vtkDataArray.newInstance({
        values: values,
        numberOfComponents: 1, // number of channels (grayscale)
        dataType: VtkDataTypes.FLOAT, // values encoding
        name: 'scalars'
    });

    var imageData = vtkImageData.newInstance();
    imageData.setOrigin(0, 0, 0);
    imageData.setSpacing(1, 1, 1);
    imageData.setExtent(0, width - 1, 0, height - 1, 0, depth - 1);
    imageData.getPointData().setScalars(scalars);

    var volumeMapper = vtkVolumeMapper.newInstance();
    volumeMapper.setInputData(imageData);
    volumeMapper.setSampleDistance(0.7);

    var volumeActor = vtkVolume.newInstance();
    volumeActor.setMapper(volumeMapper);

    initProps(volumeActor.getProperty());

    var view3d = document.getElementById("view3d");
    var fullScreenRenderer = vtkFullScreenRenderWindow.newInstance({
        rootContainer: view3d,
        containerStyle: {
            height: '100%',
            overflow: 'hidden'
        },
        background: [0, 0, 0]
    });

    var renderer = fullScreenRenderer.getRenderer();
    renderer.addVolume(volumeActor);
    renderer.resetCamera();
    renderer.getActiveCamera().elevation(-70);
    renderer.updateLightsGeometryToFollowCamera();

    var renderWindow = fullScreenRenderer.getRenderWindow();
    renderWindow.render();
}

function initProps(property) {
    property.setRGBTransferFunction(0, newColorFunction());
    property.setScalarOpacity(0, newOpacityFunction());
    property.setScalarOpacityUnitDistance(0, 4.5);
    property.setInterpolationTypeToLinear();
    property.setUseGradientOpacity(0, true);
    property.setGradientOpacityMinimumValue(0, 0, 5);
    property.setGradientOpacityMinimumOpacity(0, 0.0);

    property.setGradientOpacityMaximumValue(0, 1);
    property.setGradientOpacityMaximumOpacity(0, 1.0);
    property.setShade(true);
    property.setAmbient(0.2);
    property.setDiffuse(0.7);
    property.setSpecular(0.3);
    property.setSpecularPower(8.0);

}

function newColorFunction() {
    var fun = vtkColorTransferFunction.newInstance();
    fun.addRGBPoint(0, 0.4, 0.2, 0.0);
    fun.addRGBPoint(1, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    return fun;
}

function newOpacityFunction() {
    var fun = vtkPiecewiseFunction.newInstance();
    fun.addPoint(0, 0);
    fun.addPoint(0.5, 0);
    fun.addPoint(0.5, 1);
    fun.addPoint(1, 1);
    return fun;
}

initRandomCubeVolume();
```

```css
#view3d { height: calc(100vh - 20px); /* avoid scrollbar because of margins */ }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vtk.js"></script>
<div id="view3d"></div>
```

[Resistance is futile!](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=the+borg+cube&ia=images&iax=images)